# Security Exception with Policies in my VS Code

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio

The exception:

```
About_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ ng serve
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem comes when:

1. You restart your VS code / System / Computer
   or
2. You update your windows.

Solution: Type:

```
npm start
```

and hit Enter.
This simple command will solve the problem.